# Unable to create plateform for gcm on AWS

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I have created plateform for ios app and it is created fine on aws server but when I have tried to create gcm plateform on sns section it is giving error. I have attached the image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got exactly same issue as yours. It seems google is migrating Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to Google Cloud Messaging, and the API Key created via Credentials in API Manager of Google Cloud Platform is not working.

And here is how I get it to work.

1. Go to [Firebase Console](http://console.firebase.google.com) and import Google Cloud Project.
2. Go to Project settings on Firebase Console and you should see the Web API
   Key of your project.
3. Go back to your Google Cloud Platform, and go to Credentials of API Manager, you should see there are two API keys have been generated. Browser key (auto created by Google Service) and Server key (auto created by Google Service)
4. The Server key (auto created by Google Service) is what you need to
   use on the Amazon SNS.

Hope it can resolve your problem, and hope it is only a temporary solution that after Google done the migration, we can directly use the API key created in API Manager.

Comment: You can see the Server API key in the Firebase Project settings

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you are using the correct server key. It should be something like `AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA`.